# Access build pipeline output variable in Environment Approval / Check

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to build an automatic Environment Approval with *Invoke Azure Function*. I need to pass a variable that is created in a previous build stage. I have added the variable to the function body, but the variable is not evaluated:

Task that creates the output variable (in previous stage)

```yaml
    - task: CmdLine@2
      inputs:
        script: |
          # Debug output (value visible in logs)
          pulumi stack output resourceGroupName
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=resourceGroupName;isoutput=true]$(pulumi stack output resourceGroupName)"
       workingDirectory: 'infra'
```

Body for the Azure function:

```
    { "ResourceGroup": "$(resourceGroupName)" }
```

Log:

```
    2020-03-26T15:57:01.2590351Z POST https://azure-function-url
    Request body: {
       "ResourceGroup": "$(resourceGroupName)"
    }
```

Comment: I did face similar issue. To clarify your question, you appear to be asking about https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass. The question doesn't seem to be just asking about how to trigger Azure function, instead... how to access variable in "subsequent check/gate execution", where it appears variables don't seem expanded.

Comment: btw, I think I figured out my issue. A deployment check/gate is executed before all jobs in a phase. This means none of the variables set in current phase would be present when check is being executed. But, pre-defined variables like `$(BUILD.BUILDID)` are available.

Comment: I see you can override  variables sent to deployment-task here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61656077/implementing-gates-in-azure-yaml-pipelines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Added the variable to the function body, but the variable is not
>   evaluated

This is a expected action. Here what you are doing is `share variable across stages`, which does not supported directly until now.

*[`Output variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#use-output-variables-from-tasks) just used to share values between **steps** instead of **stages**.*

**Work around**:

If you want to use the generated variable in next stage, a workaround you can consider to use is writing the variable to a file, leveraging pipeline artifacts.

Sample steps:

Here I will pass one variable which name is `resourceGroupName` to next stage.

**1)** Create a folder which will contain the variables you want to pass

```
   mkdir -p $(Pipeline.Workspace)/variables
```

**2)** Write the contents of the variable to file `StageUsed`:

```
 echo "$resourceGroupName" > $(Pipeline.Workspace)/variables/StageUsed
```

**3)** In next stage, add one job before your `InvokeAzureFunction` job. Download the variables pipeline artifact that previous stage published.

**4)** Transfer each file into a variable:

```
 resourceGroupName=$(cat $(Pipeline.Workspace)/variables/StageUsed)
```

**5)** Make the variable exposed in the current job, and set it reference name as `Out`:

```
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=resourceGroupName;isoutput=true]$resourceGroupName"
```

**6)** Now, you can access the variable in your `InvokeAzureFunction` job by calling dependencies.secondjob.outputs['output.resourceGroupName']

**Sample Script:**

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
  - stage: FirstStage
    jobs:
      - job: firstjob
        pool:
          vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04'
        steps:
          - bash: |
              resourceGroupName="value"
              mkdir -p $(Pipeline.Workspace)/variables
              echo "$resourceGroupName" > $(Pipeline.Workspace)/variables/resourceGroupName

          - publish: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/variables
            artifact: variables

  - stage: SecondStage
    jobs:
      - job: secondjob
        pool:
          vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04'
        steps:
          - download: current
            artifact: variables
          - bash: |
              resourceGroupName=$(cat $(Pipeline.Workspace)/variables/resourceGroupName)
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=resourceGroupName;isoutput=true]$resourceGroupName"
            name: output
          - bash: |
              echo "$(output.resourceGroupName)"

      - job: ServerJob
        dependsOn: secondjob
        pool: server
        variables:
          resourceGroupName: $[dependencies.secondjob.outputs['output.resourceGroupName']]
        steps:
          - task: AzureFunction@1
            inputs:
              function: 
              method: 'POST'
              body: '$(sdf)'
              waitForCompletion: 'false'
```

Comment: You are suggesting to call AzureFunction directly. Author appears to ask how to expand variables when calling AzureFunctions in "approval and checks" defined here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass#invoke-azure-function. 
This is not equivalent to calling AzureFunctions directly from YAML.