# Can we raise and merge a pull request from Azure Devops pipelines?

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pull-request, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a release branch through which I am executing the CI/CD yaml Pipelines and deploying the application in different environments on AKS.

Once my UAT deployment stage completes, I want to create a Pull Request and merge the branches if no conflicts, from release branch to master branch. And on completion of Pull Request only, the stage for PROD deployment should start.

Is there any task/script which will help me achieve my goal?

I have checked [Create Pull Request](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ShaykiAbramczyk.CreatePullRequest) extension, but currently it supports only Windows machines.

I also read about Azure DevOps REST APIs to create a Pull Request, but it was mentioned that the API supports 2 commits only.

Any help here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the P[ull Requests - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) Rest Api to create a Pull request as Shayki Abramczyk mentioned. See [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1#examples).

However, there is an easier way which is using the Create Pull Request extension in an additional agent job and run this job on a windows agent. See below steps:

1, Add another agent job in your UAT deployment stage.

[image]

2, Add Create Pull Request task to create the Pull request.

If you want the stage for PROD deployment to be started automatically on the completion of the Pull Request. You can consider using the Invoke rest api Gate for the PROD deployment stage. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deploy-using-approvals?view=azure-devops#set-up-gates) for more information about Gate. You can refer to below steps:

1, Create a generic service connection to connect to your azure devops project.

Navigate to project settings-->Service connections-->New service connection-->Generic
[image]

[image]

**Server URL: https://dev.azure.com/OrgName/ProjName**

**Password: Personal Access Token**

2, Add a invoke rest api Gate for PROD deployment stage.

[image]

invoke rest api Gate will invoke the [Pull Requests - Get Pull Requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/get%20pull%20requests?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) rest api to get the Pull request created in UAT stage. And the gate can only be passed when the Pull request is completed.

**URL suffix and parameters: /_apis/git/repositories/{RepoId}/pullrequests?searchCriteria.sourceRefName=refs/heads/{sourceBranchName}&searchCriteria.targetRefName=refs/heads/{TargetBranchName}&$top=1&api-version=6.1-preview.1**

**Success criteria: not(root['value'][0])**

Update:

To use above invoke rest api in yaml pipeline. You need to use [deployment job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs?view=azure-devops) and define approvals and checks for your environment.

See [approvals and checks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass) for more information.

Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops) for more information about environment,

See this thread [Implementing Gates in Azure YAML Pipelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61656077/implementing-gates-in-azure-yaml-pipelines)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I am not using Release pipelines but using YAML pipelines. Will check how can we integrate the above mentioned approach in YAML

Comment: @ShrijitNarkar You can use above invoke rest api task by using deployment job and define approvals and checks for your environment. See above update.

Comment: I tried adding Invoke REST API Gate on my production environment variable. The issue I'm facing now is, the gate doesn't pass. It keeps on waiting for success criteria to be met. The URL suffix which I have used is: /_apis/git/repositories/$(Build.Repository.Name)/pullrequests?searchCriteria.sourceRefName=refs/heads/demo_release&searchCriteria.targetRefName=refs/heads/demo_master&$top=1&api-version=5.0
Does this variable $(Build.Repository.Name) get resolved in the approval gate? In your example you have provided the repo id directly.

Comment: @ShrijitNarkar Could you check if there is any error message in the log of the Invoke REST API Gate?

Answer (score 0):

In Linux you can use [PowerShell core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell) and [rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) to create the PR:

```
$body =  @{
             sourceRefName= "refs/heads/feature"
             targetRefName = "refs/heads/master"
             title = "PR from Pipeline"
     }

$head = @{ Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"  }
$json = ConvertTo-Json $body
$url = "$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/git/repositories/$(Build.Repository.Name)/pullrequests?api-version=5.0"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Post -Headers $head -Body $json -ContentType application/json
```

Comment: Thank you! I will test and respond back

Comment: I used your task by executing it on Windows VM and it has worked. Now I'm trying to add and an approval gate as suggested by Levi Lu in his answer to check if PR has been merged or not by invoking REST API. CreatePullRequest task provides PullRequestId in the response in variable $(pullRequestId). Can you please guide me how can we use this variable in the URL suffix for Invoke REST API Approval gate?
I tried following URL suffix: /_apis/git/repositories/$(Build.Repository.Name)/pullrequests/$(pullRequestId)?api-version=5.0 
But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I don't think the `$(pullRequestId)` is available in the gate :/ it's only available in the tasks.